# Return an element's particular event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling

Given an element in the Dom, is it possible to return the name of the event handler for a particular event?

For instance,if i select an element

```
$("#container")
```

Is it possible to return the 'keypress' eventhandler bound to that element?

Comment: what's the ultimate intention?

Comment: I need to get the event handlers in a page for a browser extension i am working on.

Comment: jQuery will only know about event handlers that we're created using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This post may help: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/

> You can access all event handlers bound to an element (or any object) through jQuery’s event storage:

```
// List bound events:
console.dir( jQuery('#elem').data('events') );

// Log ALL handlers for ALL events:
jQuery.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        console.log( handler.toString() );
    });
});

// You can see the actual functions which will occur
// on certain events; great for debugging!
```

Comment: I just noticed, "jQuery (edge)" uses the latest alpha version of jQuery lol... and I've been using this option for quite some time in my demos.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it using : `$('#container').attr('keypress')`

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, if you're using a named function (although this is kind of an odd thing to be doing in the first place...).

```
// create a named function
function fooHandler() {}

// bind the named function
$("#container").keypress(fooHandler);

// retrieve the bound function from the data collection
$("#container").data('events').keypress[0].handler.name; // 'fooHandler'
```

Comment: I think this only works for events created using jquery. I am trying to get the events from page which is already loaded from a browser extension.